# For how long can you keep a laptop on without damage?

Tags: laptop, battery

I want to know if its safe to keep laptop on for 6-7 hours straight. I have Sony VAIO CW26.

Comment: There's a power switch?

Answer (score 7):

You can keep it on for 6-7 days straight. Months even. Unless your wife gets angry that you've not showered or bathed for 6-7 days straight and haven't said anything more than a guttural growl when she tells you she wants to go out to dinner or do something requiring your attention. That might be detrimental to your health.

Comment: +1 for not showering.  Quite the liberating feeling.  The only thing that can beat it is bacon.

Comment: +1 to Holocryptic for Bacon. Mmmm, tasty tasty bacon...

Comment: +1 for putting those two close enough to think of bacon showers

Comment: Two words: [bacon pancakes](http://johnnycat.wordpress.com/2010/06/15/bacon-pancakes/)

Comment: @Dennis, I just drooled all over myself.  srsly.

Comment: If I could upvote my own answer I would, simply for the epic comment thread it spawned. And a pancake recipe.

Comment: A BACON pancake recipe.  Show proper respect.

Comment: @Holocryptic: True 'dat. I need to find some maple butter and bacon now...

Answer (score 5):

Forever (provided it's not overheating or being shaken/thrown around while it's running).

All components have both a service life & a cycle life (how long they can run continuously & how many times you can start/stop them): No matter what you do you'll exhaust one before the other, so just use the machine however it best suits your needs.

Comment: Of course, many home users do in fact overheat their laptops on a routine basis, usually by operating them on soft surfaces.

Comment: @Miles ... even those of us who know better are guilty of that occasionally.

Comment: @Miles: I've had my MacBook hit 204 on the CPU before. Running on a flat hard surface though.

Answer (score -2):

Leave it on for couple of days and switch it off for an hour or so and then again you can restart it for 2 more days provided it's plugged in

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).